# Custom MP3 response to voice command

Tags: mp3, customization, actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I would like my Google Home to respond with a sound byte (mp3) to commands such as "Turn off Living Room Lights". Anyone know how I accomplish this?

Comment: You are unable to programmatically send audio data to a Google Home, unless you had some sort of setup that also sent "OK Google" at the start.

Comment: Well, I would say, "Ok Google, Turn off the Lights" and instead of responding "Okay, turning off 3 lights" I want it to play the MP3

Comment: Ah, there is no way to do that, as home control is a direct action and it's not something that a developer can customize.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Media Response](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#media_responses). There are lots of ways to do that. Please go through the link and use the one that suits your requirement.

Comment: I did use media response, and uploaded my MP4 to Google Play Music, but its SUPER inconsistent as to whether or not it plays the media file, tells me its not available, or plays some random playlist instead. Is there a way to create consistency?